# Cmake install nested static library target_link_library undefined reference

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, static-libraries, undefined-reference

Install nested static library, and target_link_library not working

File structure:

```
HelloLib
    WorldLib
        CMakeLists.txt
        WorldLib.cpp
        WorldLib.h

    CMakeLists.txt
    HelloLib.cpp
    HelloLib.h

CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "HelloLib/HelloLib.h"
int main() {
  std::cout << hello() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt (root)

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(HelloLib)
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    HelloLib
)
```

HelloLib.cpp

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "WorldLib/WorldLib.h"
std::string hello() { return "Hello " + world(); }
```

HelloLib.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
std::string hello();
```

CMakeLists.txt (HelloLib)

```cpp
add_library(HelloLib HelloLib.cpp)

add_subdirectory(WorldLib)
target_link_libraries(
    HelloLib
    WorldLib
)
```

WorldLib.cpp

```cpp
#include <string>
std::string world() { return "World!"; }
```

WorldLib.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
std::string world();
```

CMakeLists.txt (WorldLib)

```cpp
add_library(WorldLib WorldLib.cpp)
```

Build and run, successfully print out `Hello World!`

Now I would like to make HelloLib as static library

Change CMakeLists.txt (HelloLib), install to `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include`

```cpp
add_library(HelloLib HelloLib.cpp)

add_subdirectory(WorldLib)
target_link_libraries(
    HelloLib
    WorldLib
)

install(
    TARGETS HelloLib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)
install(
    DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/" # source directory
    DESTINATION "include" # target directory
    FILES_MATCHING # install only matched files
    PATTERN "*.h" # select header files
)
```

Run (`make install`) (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`/usr`)

```bash
mkdir -p out/build
cmake -S src -B out/build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
cd out/build
make
make install
```

```cpp
[ 33%] Built target WorldLib
[ 66%] Built target HelloLib
[100%] Built target HelloWorld
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libHelloLib.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/include
-- Installing: /usr/include/HelloLib
-- Installing: /usr/include/HelloLib/HelloLib.h
-- Installing: /usr/include/HelloLib/WorldLib
-- Installing: /usr/include/HelloLib/WorldLib/WorldLib.h
```

Static library (.a) should generate to `/usr/lib/libHelloLib.a`

Let's test it, change CMakeLists.txt (root)

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(HelloLib)
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}

    /usr/lib/libHelloLib.a
)
```

Then build, it give undefined reference error

```
/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libHelloLib.a(HelloLib.cpp.o): in function `hello[abi:cxx11]()':
HelloLib.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `world[abi:cxx11]()'
```

What's wrong with me? This can be successful with no nested library

What is the correct way to install nested static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the install process but the fact that you link only to `libHelloLib.a`.

Your `libHelloLib.a` need the symbol in `libWorldLib.a` because `libHelloLib.a` is a static lib and so only contains its own symbol. It does not contains the symbol `world` that is defined in `libWorldLib.a`.

To make your project works, you need to install `WorldLib` and `HelloLib` and links against this two lib.

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    HelloLib
    WorldLib
)
```

Or you can change `HelloLib` into a shared library. This way the `libHelloLib.so` will also contains the symbol of `WorldLib`.

You can also look at this [Exported Target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets).
It's an install command that will create some `FindXX.cmake` file that you will be able to use with the `find_package` command. You also will be able to defined the dependency of your lib. But if you want that `HelloLib` stay a static library you will have to install `WorldLib`